# Consuming Web Services in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, service, soa

I've setup a project in Netbeans 6.5 with some web services that I've created myself and some web services that I've imported from WSDL files. I've setup a couple of desktop application through Netbeans in order to consume these web services. I'm not too sure where to go from here.

I have the GUI setup but not sure how to reference the web services so they can be consumed. I was wondering would anybody be able to guide me through this process or point me in the direction of a relevant tutorial. I'd also like to learn how to consume a web service through a JSP (also created in Netbeans) if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this tutorial useful:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html, but since you are using Netbean 6.5 this may be the correct version:
http://netbeans.org/kb/61/websvc/client.html.  As the steps show, it isn't difficult to build a jax-ws client using Netbeans.

But, it depends on what version of Java you are using also, most likely. You may want to download the latest version of jax-ws, if you get errors with your wsdl.

For a JSP, just create a custom tag to call the client.